# setPluginEnabled is undefined

Tags: java, android

here is the code i dont know why this 
this method `setPluginsEnabled` is undefined 
try to deprecation this but it doesnt work  ??????

```
public class Webv extends Activity{

WebView webview;



public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
     webview = new WebView(this);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_webv);
     webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wvVideos);
     webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            }
        });

     webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
     webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
     webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
     webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
     webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

     webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
     webview.invokeZoomPicker();
     webview.loadUrl(getIntent().getStringExtra("nameseries"));
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    webview.loadData("", "text/html", "utf-8");
}

}
```

Comment: What version of android are you compiling at? Right click your project, hit properties, then click android and see which api level you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html, there is no method `setPluginsEnabled` for WebSettings. Maybe it's an older method that has been removed in newer versions?

Additionally, the text next to `setPluginState` reads:

> This method was deprecated in API level 18. Plugins will not be
>   supported in future, and should not be used.

You should probably follow that advice.

Comment: and what I should use insteed of this method

Comment: I think the idea is that you find another way of doing what you want to do that doesn't require plugins.