# webview setPluginEnabled(boolean) undefined

Tags: android, webview

I try to show local `HTML` in webview but it showing error.

**Here's the source**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView wv= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
    wv.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true); //error here
    WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
}
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: What error is showing?

Comment: It say "The menthod setPluginEnabled(boolean) is undefined for the type WebString"

Comment: Check this other question to see if helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19362049/setpluginsenabled-not-exist-for-webview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"This method was deprecated in API level 18. Plugins will not be supported in future, and should not be used."

see the question wich brings you the nswer : [setPluginEnabled is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359264/setpluginenabled-is-undefined)